# Tips for anime style swift movement and teleportion effects for blender 2.9

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, effects

I'm trying to figure out how to do anime style swift movements or teleportation like effects but what I do have is either laggy as all hell or effects the background and other objects. I would rather it be in real time, would like to avoid compositing, but if it's the only way then fine. Also, the effect has to effect a single character, nothing around them, unless the other character is moving too. Also, I would like the effect to be flexible, so I can make variants or use it on a single body part.

I’m currently using 2.91 and the eevee. Pictures or videos would be really helpful.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question more than once, instead edit your original one and address the issues in the comments. [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) As it sands this question isn't really answerable, it is too broad and it would take a lengthy tutorial to answer. It is also unclear what you are trying to achieve. Are your characters 2D or 3D? Do you need a 3D effect, 2D? Could it be done in compositing?

Comment: Can this be reopened. There's not much I can do to simplify it as it's a single effect. Also, I don't know if it can be done in compositing, that's why I'm asking, but I would like to avoid using it.

Comment: Seriously, does anyone know how to do it in real time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [KeyMesh](https://youtu.be/c6CqP2fNFlY) which is an addon that will create frame to frame animation (model your speed lines, duplicate, deform, etc..)

Or you can try another 2D approach using grease pencil by [following this tutorial>>](https://youtu.be/3autQgdvsbU)
which basically shows you how to apply grease pencil over a specific layer. You'd create your character's "smeared" colors and then animate as the video shows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *exactly* what you're looking for (i.e. a full body teleport, vs some arms moving really fast), I think you can get a pretty close effect by putting a plane in front of your character, and using an animated noise texture and a holdout shader to render parts of what's behind the plane transparent, and then composite your character on top of the scene.

So you'd have a noise texture that's stretched on one axis to create the distorted lines, then use that to punch out sections of the render.
[image: Instant Transmission]

By animating the transparency of your character, you can also have them start to snap in and out of view to add to the effect.
Here's a Blend file that should go over what's up.
https://files.catbox.moe/rntcdz.blend

Comment: I know OP said they'd like to avoid the compositor, but this would probably be much easier to do with the character rendered on a different layer altogether.

Comment: I did mention to comp the character on top of the background layer. Depending on how you work, it could be easier or harder to do purely in compositing, but the general idea remains the same. I just did it all in the 3d viewport since he asked for as little compositing as possible. Though it looks like the questions and answers are going on 2 years old now, so what help I really gave, I don't know. It was at the top of the list and seemed like a fun little exercise.

Comment: The reason I wanted to avoid it is I think, at the time, you couldn't view all the layers at once, only one at a time and you couldn't edit them. I can't remember if you can now, tho. I was going to have entire scenes, backgrounds, and other characters I needed to animate. So putting them on different layers would make it way harder. I wanted something I could see in real time, so I can see if something needed to be changed before rendering. Then having other effects in composite.